# How can this function produce Java.Lang.NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, crash, java-native-interface

I am getting random crashes from some users.  It's happening to a small minority of users, but I can't figure out what in this code would work about 99% of the time and fail the other 1%.

This is the crash as reported by Google Play:

java.lang.NullPointerException:
1. at com.raptisoft.SB.SBActivity.IsPurchased (Unknown Source:13)
2. at com.raptisoft.SB.GameThread.AppThread (Native Method)
3. at com.raptisoft.SB.GameThread.run (Unknown Source:2)
4. at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:784)

And here is the function it crashes in:

```
Bundle mOwnedItems; // Filled elsewhere

private boolean IsPurchased(String theData)
{
    if (theData==null) return false;
    boolean aResult=false;
    if (mOwnedItems.size()>0) if (mOwnedItems.containsKey("RESPONSE_CODE"))
    {
        int response = mOwnedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
        if (response == 0 && mOwnedItems.containsKey("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST"))
        {
            ArrayList<String> ownedSkus = new ArrayList<String>();
            ownedSkus = mOwnedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST");
            if (ownedSkus!=null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < ownedSkus.size(); ++i) {
                    String sku = ownedSkus.get(i);
                    if (sku.equals(theData)) {
                        aResult = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return aResult;
}
```

...which in turn is called from this function in the native code:

```
bool ToJava::IsPurchased(char* theData)
{
    if (theData==NULL) return false;

    JNIEnv* threadEnv=GetEnv();
    jstring aPassString = threadEnv->NewStringUTF(theData);
    jboolean aResult=threadEnv->CallBooleanMethod(g_theGlobalRefToActivityInstance,gIsPurchasedBridge,aPassString);
    threadEnv->DeleteLocalRef(aPassString);

    return (aResult!=0);
}
```

I have been chasing this crash down for two weeks, adding more and more safeguards to the function-- and yet it's still happening.  I'm only middling at Java, since my preferred language is C++.  Can anyone enlighten me on what might be null in this function?

Comment: What is line 13? --> `at com.raptisoft.SB.SBActivity.IsPurchased (Unknown Source:13)`. Any object at the left side of the dot (`.`) at that line can be the source. Use `System.out.println()` to print those values, or use a debugger, set a breakpoint and inspect the variables.

Comment: We don't know what line 13 is.

Comment: I can't print it out because I can't manifest the crash.  It happens on a small minority of devices, and I don't know what circumstances.  So my only recourse is to examine the code for weak points.

But sometimes the crash is reported on line 16 instead.   (Also, wouldn't putting in statements to print the line numbers change the line numbers?)

Comment: Which line is line 13?

Comment: You gotta show us the code in `com.raptisoft.SB.SBActivity` or there's little chance we can guess the problem.

Comment: That IsPurchased function is a function from com.raptisoft.SB.SBActivity.

Comment: What does mOwnedItems look like? How is the data stored?

Comment: mOwnedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);   ...it's from Google Play Services, to see which items have been purchased in the play store.  It just returns a Bundle.

Comment: Your issue is most likely after ownedSkus != null. That statement will always be true for an ArrayList. So even if ownedSkus was empty it'd still proceed to the for loop. Change ownedSkus != null to !ownedSkus.isEmpty()

Comment: Thanks!  That's the kind of thing where my Java weakness shows up!

Comment: @StephenCorcoran *Change ownedSkus != null to !ownedSkus.isEmpty()*  No.  That *will* cause an NPE if `mOwnedItems.getStringArrayList()` returns `null`.  The code as originally posted is fine - if it's not `null`, iterate over the elements.  The most likely problem - if it's in the posted code - is that `mOwnedItems` is somehow `null`.

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/android/os/Bundle.java

Comment: @StephenCorcoran Do you mean [this line](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/android/os/Bundle.java#1306) where `getStringArrayList()` explicitly returns `null`?

Comment: Yeah, for the record, that fix didn't work, I've already got my new set of crashes.  I also had thrown in a check for if mOwnedItems wasn't null too, and that hasn't helped anything.  So, if anyone else has any ideas, I'd like to hear.  Still unable to duplicate it for myself, on any of my devices.

Comment: Try checking for a null `sku`. i.e. `if ((sku != null) && sku.equals(theData))`

Comment: If you did if(theData.equals(sku)) instead of if(sku.equals(theData)). That case handles if sku is null and returns false instead of throwing a NullPointerException